# Missing characters in parsed XML output with PHP5

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to parse the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE content PUBLIC "-//BLACKWELL PUBLISHING GROUP//DTD 4.0//EN" "http://www.blackwellpublishing.com/xml/dtds/4-0/bpg4-0.dtd">
<content dtdver="4.0" docfmt="xml">
....
<forenames>NIELS B&Oslash;IE</forenames><x> </x>
```

At first it wouldn't load, but now I have code which at least seems to use the DTD to figure out the entity like `&Oslash;` (Ø), but the next problem is that it doesn't show the character in the output.

This is my parsing code:

```
$options = LIBXML_DTDLOAD | LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_DTDVALID | LIBXML_NOCDATA;
$doc = simplexml_load_string ( $xml,null,$options );
echo $doc->document->header->namegroup->name->forenames."\n";
```

This is the output:

NIELS BIE

I tried it with DOM XML parsing too, and then the output was NIELS B IE (so with a space..)

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the DTD, it says this (but without line breaks):

```
<!ENTITY Oslash 
    "<symbol name='Oslash' unicode='00D8'
     type='html' glyph='@Oslash;' description='capital O, slash' 
     ascii='O' > </symbol>"
>
```

To any XML reader using this DTD, this means "Whenever you see this exact combination of letters in the source: `&Oslash;`, replace it with this text: `<symbol name='Oslash' unicode... > </symbol>`

This means that the XML data actually reads like this:

```
<forenames>NIELS B<symbol name='Oslash' unicode='00D8'
     type='html' glyph='@Oslash;' description='capital O, slash' 
     ascii='O' > </symbol>IE</forenames>
```

...which explains why it's not showing up in your browser. The way around it would be to search your XML document for all `<symbol>` elements, read the `unicode` parameter and replace them with that.

---

Looking further at it, the comments at the top of the DTD show they've considered people in your situation! The `glyph` attribute on the `<symbol>` tag is the standard HTML entity to use for that symbol, but with the ampersand replaced with an @.

```
10 read xml document
20 search for any <symbol> element
30 read the "glyph" attribute
40 remove the <symbol> element
50 replace the @ with an & in glyph
60 write that in the place of <symbol>
70 goto 20
```

Comment: I'd still expect my browser to show symbol then if I view the source, but it might be that because it's within the element I have to parse it differently for it to show up..I'll experiment.

Comment: but there is no Ø symbol... `&Oslash;` is being replaced with `<symbol ...>` when your XML reader parses it.

Comment: yeah I get that. I was just thinking the <symbol..> part would show up in view source, but as it is an element within the forenames one the way I was looking at the xml I think it is now shown. I need to look at nested symbol tags too...

Comment: nope, just the same as how when you look at the source of a HTML document, you still see `&eacute;` - the actual source code isn't changed, it's only when it's parsed into a DOM tree. Also, the symbols will never be nested within each other, and using an XPath query of `"//symbol"` will find them all.

Comment: ok. Getting closer I think. The XPath is finding the symbols, now I need to figure out how to replace a node with some other content...

Comment: `$textNode = document.createTextNode($unicodeChar); $symbol->parentNode->insertBefore($textNode, $symbol); $symbol->parentNode->removeChild($symbol);`

Answer (score 2):

The DTD you are using with your XML file there doesn't contain the Oslash entity. As such the XML parser simply doesn't know what to do with Ø and confusion and/or hilarity ensues.

It is important to separate HTML's notion of named entities (of which Oslash is part) from XML's notion of named entities (apos, lt, gt, quot, amp). Basically, if it's not HTML, there's no Oslash (at least in the general case, some DTDs may have it, but it might not be the character you want at all.

In other words; always use UTF-8. Always.

EDIT: Ø is in latin-1, too.

Comment: one of the mods that is defined in the dtd seem to have it:
http://www.blackwellpublishing.com/xml/dtds/4-0/bpg4-0entities.mod, and as PHP was throwing an entity not found error before I added the correct url for the dtd I think PHP is probably parsing this?

Comment: Well, that's what i get for not fully resolving the DTD mentally...
Irrespectively, that DTD has a rather perverse manner of defining that entity, it'd probably be a WAY better idea to use the Ø verbatim in any case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have correct encoding you dont need to escape `&Oslash;` (Ø). Try to use unicode to be sure.

If there is no way to change the behavior try unescaping HTML entities, check PHP manual.

Comment: I get the feeling this doc comes from elsewhere.

Comment: yeah, I'm parsing it, not writing it.

Comment: Ow, its too bad they dont know how to produce XML. IMO only method left is to replace HTML entities before parsing. PHP has a function for it.

Comment: as I commented above, I think it is valid to define entities in the DTD, and in the mod http://www.blackwellpublishing.com/xml/dtds/4-0/bpg4-0entities.mod the entity *is* defined. The character is just not being used somehow

Comment: If the data is from elsewhere surely DTD is defined by someone else and IMO it will not be logical to duplicate and change it.

Answer (score 0):

ok, got a bit further, if I user var_dump instead of echo I get this:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[22]
  public 'symbol' => 
  object(SimpleXMLElement)[21]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'Oslash' (length=6)
      'unicode' => string '00D8' (length=4)
      'type' => string 'html' (length=4)
      'glyph' => string '@Oslash;' (length=8)
      'description' => string 'capital O, slash' (length=16)
      'ascii' => string 'O' (length=1)
  string ' ' (length=1)
```

I wonder how I can use that to make a complete string together with the contents of forenames